# Reference request for representation theory of TRO

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, c-star-algebras

Let $H$ and $K$ be Hilbert spaces. Recall that a Ternary ring of operator(TRO) $V$ is a closed subspace of $B(H,K)$ such that $xy^{\ast}z \in V$ for all $x,y,z \in V$. I have recently started reading about TROs. I am interested in studying about representation theory of TRO. As I am beginner i am interested in learning basics of the same first.

> What are some papers/books to read about the representation theory of TRO?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Zettl's thesis is of course the main reference.  I think David Blecher has written a lot about TRO's from the point of view of operator spaces.  I have also considered some aspects of TRO's in relation to partial actions in "Twisted partial actions, a classification of regular C*-algebraic bundles", Proc. London Math. Soc., 74 (1997), 417-443.

Comment: The introduction to the paper "Local properties of Ternary Rings of Operators and their linking C*-algebras" by Kaur and Ruan (JFA 2002)  has several references (including the 2 mentioned by Ruy) about TROs.  My relationship with TROs was short and long ago but I don't remember seeing a systematic study of their representation theory anywhere. It is probably closely tied to the representation theory of the linking C*-algebras which already has a fully developed theory.

Comment: @CalebEckhardt: Do you know any paper where the relationship  between representation of C*- algebras and its linking C*-algebras has been established?

Comment: @MathLover In Section 2 of the  Kaur-Ruan paper they outline, with reference to Hamana, how a TRO morphism gives rise to a C*-algebra morphism of the linking C*-algebras.

Comment: @CalebEckhardt: Thank you. I still don’t see how a morphism of C*- algebras gives rise to a TRO morphism. Any ideas?